# expo init gives the error "× Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the template. npm exited with non-zero code: 1"

Tags: expo

so I am trying to get started with react native

**when I tried running expo init it gave me the following error:**

```
√ What would you like to name your app? ... test

√ Choose a template: » minimal

× Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the template.

npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
```

any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of outdated but figured out that I can use a docker container or WSL.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).